# Why does Google chart not show the Axis data values?

Tags: javascript, api, visualization, charts

If you visit the URL below you will see that the graph is being generated properly, but that there are not labels along the x and y axis to indicate the data values:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=600x300&chtt=Release+Burndown&cht=lc&chdl=estimated|actual&chco=FF0000,00FF00&chxr=0,0,30,2|1,0,40,2&chds=0,45&chd=t:45,34,23,12,0|45,20,15,32,31,25,0

Can anyone figure out how to get the x and y axis data values to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API, you can do this through the chxX parameters:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts.html#gcharts_axis_styles_labels

chx1: make custom values as labels
chxs and chxtc:  to specify color, size, alignment, and other properties of both custom and numeric axis labels

Let me know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I am specifying chxr=0,0,45,2|1,0,45,2 but the axis values still do not show, any ideas? EDIT: was missing the CHXT parameter to specific the visible axis

Comment: Good! Glad you figured it out.